# Extract fixed number of Median_high Values of a list

Tags: python, list, statistics, median

I have a list of values of variable length and want to reduce/filter the list to a fixed length of n values by keeping statistics.median_high values, how would you do that ?

I'm currently thinking of something like :

- finding median_high of the list
- create 2 sublists : above and below the median_high, and calculating median_high of this sublists
- etc...

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Please provide sample input, expected output and the code you're having trouble with

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.